# Hibernate search ignore analyzer in query

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I'm trying to query a field with a custom field bridge that aggregates two fields. A typical value looks like this:

```
myField:12345%FIELDSEPERATOR%4
```

This is the combination of 12345 and 4. It is indexed correctly, but using hibernate search query API, how can I disable the analyzer?

```
FullTextEntityManager em = getFTEM();
SearchFactory searchFactory = em.getSearchFactory();
QueryBuilder qb = searchFactory.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
Query q = qb.phrase()
            .onField("myField")
            .ignoreAnalyzer()
            .sentence("12345%SEPERATOR%4")
            .createQuery();
```

q here is parsed to `myField:"12345 seperator 4"` which breaks the search, even though I specified ignoreAnalyzer. To compare, the following generates a working query

```
TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term("myField", "12345%SEPERATOR%4"));
```

Result query: `myField:"12345%SEPERATOR%4"`

I know I could simply use TermQuery instead, but I'd like to enjoy the easy other features of Hibernate search such as .boostedTo().

Using Hibernate Search 3.4.2 that internally uses Lucene 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're defining a *phrase* Query, you should use *keyword*

```
Query q = qb.keyword()
    .onField( "myField" )
    .matching( "12345%SEPERATOR%4" )
    .createQuery();
```

Comment: Ah, I used phrase query since i saw examples combining fields in a single string that said phrase query was needed. Thanks!

Comment: Introduces new issues though... just replacing phrase to keyword causes an org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to find field myField in com.my.app.User, even though there most definetly exist such a field. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RasmusFranke I think you may need to post a new question, where you could show the pertinent parts of com.my.app.User, to get a decent answer on that.

Comment: Fair enough, though ill probably use the pure lucene api for now since it simply works

Comment: if you're using a field that is created in a classbridge, Hibernate Search won't know about it. In that case you should use ignoreFieldBridge to prevent exceptions